# Azure - Switch host name for ssl certificate

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate

I have just bought an SSL Certificate for my website from azure. when setting up a certificate under "Naked domain hostname" i entered the domain name WITHOUT "www".

Currently if i were to view my website with **https://xyz.ca**, it works just fine and it says it is secure, but if enter **www.xyz.ca** i do not see anything.

To atleast view the website with www.xyz.ca, i have removed HTTPS:// only request. However now this makes website un-secure.

Question
1. what will be the best way to make www.xyz.ca secure using the same certificate that i have bought?
2. if there is any other solution available, that will be fine too.

I am attaching some screenshots to understand better:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need a wildcard certificate, that will secure `*.xyz.ca`.  Instead of buying one via the Azure Portal, you can get a free one via https://letsencrypt.org

Comment: @Brendan Certificates bought on Azure support both the root domain and WWW

Answer (score 0):

A valid SSL certificate must match the access FQDN domain name.

One Standard certificate only could be used for one FQDN domain name, such as `www.xyz.ca` while one WildCard certificate could be used for all like `*.xyz.ca` FQDN domain name, so usually we use the same WildCard certificate for all different services. More information about [SSL Certificate Names](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/ssl-certificate-names/)

As the comment point it out, instead of buying one via the Azure Portal, you can get a free one via [letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org/)

### Update

When you purchase an app service certificate in Azure for a root domain, by default, **Azure supports hostname as a root domain name and www subdomain.** You do not need to purchase another certificate. In this case, you already have two hostnames assigned to the site. You just bind the certificate for each. If you don't see the domain name(s) in the Hostname dropdown, try refreshing the browser page or change another browser.

Comment: Certificates bought on Azure support both the root domain and WWW

Comment: @CSharpRocks You are correct. I edit it in my reply.

Answer (score 0):

In fact a cert CAN support MANY domains.  Now, whether this is something that you can add for free with the SSL provider you have chose is a different question.  Certificate Subject Alternate Name(s) are what is used for this.  For example the cert for this site allows stackexchange.com AND stackoverflow.com and a number of others and sub-domains too.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better in OP's situation to get a wildcard certificate instead?